# Regexp not working with single/double quotes

Tags: mysql, regex, database, mysql-workbench

I have a field called `myfield` that contains this string:

```
{'Content-Language': 'en', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-Generator': 'Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)', 'Link': '<https://01.org/node>; rel="shortlink"', 'Some-Header-Key': 'max-age=31; addSomething', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
```

I want to capture the `'Some-Header-Key': 'max-age=31; addSomething'` where:
1) `'Some-Header-Key'`, `max-age` are fixed values that should always be present.

2) The `addSomething` is a optional.

3) There may be one or more spaces between the double colon and the equal sign

4) The general formal is 'key': 'value', with either single or double quotes.

5) The `([^""|'])*` to say: zero or more characters that are not single or double quotes. This to capture `addSomething`.

I wrote this query:

```
select myfield
from mytable
where mycol regexp "('|"")Some-Header-Key('|"")\s*:\s*('|"")([^""|'])*max-age\s*=\s*[0-9]+([^""|'])*('|"")";
```

But it does not return anything!! although `myfield` contains the above example string.

When I copied the field value into an external text file and run the regexp in `grep`, the regexp captured the string correctly.

What is wrong in MySQL? I use MySQL workbench 8.0 in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with the `\s` in your regex expression. Versions of MySQL prior to 8 do not support this notation, you need to use the character class `[:blank:]` instead i.e.

```
where mycol regexp "('|"")Some-Header-Key('|"")[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*('|"")([^""|'])*max-age[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*[0-9]+([^""|'])*('|"")"
```

In MySQL 8, you can use `\s` but you need to escape the backslash as MySQL uses C-style escape syntax in strings, thus `\s` just translates to `s`. So change the `\s` to `\\s` and it should work:

```
where mycol regexp "('|"")Some-Header-Key('|"")\\s*:\\s*('|"")([^""|'])*max-age\\s*=\\s*[0-9]+([^""|'])*('|"")"
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hcRSzWYDEgzr13RqNFL5LE/0)

Answer (score 0):

Not single or double quotes:  `[^'"]`
Zero or more of such:  `[^'"]`

Either a single quote or two double quotes:  `('|"")`
Either a double quote or two single quotes:  `("|'')`

One of either type of quote:  `['"]` or `('|")`
A single-quoted string:  `'[^']*'`
A double-quoted string:  `"[^"]*"`
Either of the above:  `('[^']*'|"[^"]*")`

Next problem:  How to quote a regexp string:  If it contains `'` or `"`, escape that with a backslash:

```
my_json REGEXP "('[^']*'|\"[^\"]*\")"
```

If you use something that does "binding" for you, you don't need to do the escaping.  PHP has `mysqli_real_escape_string` and `add_slashes`.

But...  I you are going to use JSON, you should upgrade to MySQL 5.7 or MariaDB 10.2 so you can use JSON functions instead of REGEXP.